# After updating to MVC3 RC, why don't my View Data classes show up in the Add View dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Background:

I just updated to the RC of MVC3, and when I went to add a Stongly-Typed View, the list of classes didn't contain the class I wanted, which has been built in my project.

Now, I did compile my project, and already have several views that work correct, but their model also doesn't show up in this list.

Since the change to this dialog in RC, what is the new criteria that makes a class show up, considering none of them in my project showed up.

Answer (score 0):

They altered the way that they're displayed in MVC 3 RC. For example previously you would just scroll to:

```
Project.Data.Models.User
```

Now it's organized in reverse

```
User (Project.Data.Models)
```

This is most likely your problem. What would be nice is if they had a filter to show only local objects rather than all referenced assemblies

Comment: No, that is not it.  There are NO classes from my project in the list (I looked through all the namespaces in parenthesis, and they are all classes that are in external assemblies.

Comment: any solution, my classes went missing from that menu this morning and nothing i do fixes it, i've rebuilt, cleaned, rebuilt again, restarted my pc, cleared my temp files etc etc etc and nothing works.

Comment: Have you found a solution at all to this problem? I face this problem daily.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Clean solution and build and my view models started showing up...